# Why is selenium script not working in chrome version 60?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception 
we have selenium-java------- 2.53.0
chrmedriver version -------- 2.23
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: update to latest chrome driver and selenium driver.

Answer (score 0):

Update your chromedriver with latest version which solve your problem

**https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/**

Try this, if you further facing issue then please description